# Is there any way to recover data from LVM partition/block device?

Tags: partition, system-installation, lvm, data-recovery, ntfs

I made mistake while choosing installation type of Mint. When I realised it, I canceled format confirmation and did not go ahead with the installation.

I ended up with this. Any way to recover data from these? There were 4 NTFS partitions.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: To have a chance at recovery you'd have to either restore your GPT (the partition table information) from a backup, or recreate the partitions with the exact offsets you had before. Of course, this is assuming no partitions were resized; meaning data was not moved around. Do you have a GPT backup or do you know original exact partition offsets?

Comment: @emmanuel-rosa I don't have GPT backup but gdisk gives 'GPT: Present'. I'm not doing anything until I get my external hard drive.

Comment: Recovering data from NTFS partitions seems more like a Windows question to me.

Comment: Based on your description, it sounds like you aborted the installation between disk partitioning and partition formatting. Meaning GPT was updated (which is why you see GPT: Present) but the partition DATA themselves were left untouched. If that's the case, and you had a backup of GPT, then presumably you'd be able to restore the GPT from the backup and regain access to the original partitions. It's going to be very difficult to restore those partitions without a GPT backup or knowing the original partition offsets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `testdisk` tool to recover lost partitions.

Comment: It failed to recover partitions. I'll try again once I get my external hard drive.